# Independent events in the context of Simpson's Paradox

Tags: probability, paradoxes

I came across this problem in the book "Introduction to Probability" by Dr. Joseph K. Blitzstein and Dr. Jessica Hwang. This problem deals with the concept of independent events in the context of the Simpson's Paradox. I seem to be a little stuck in the third part of the problem. Please let me know if my approach to the rest of the question is correct. Thank You!

> **The problem goes as follows:**
>
> Simpson’s paradox says that it is possible to have events
>   $A, B, C$ such that $P(A | B,C) < P(A | B^c, C)$ and $P(A | B,C^c) < P(A | B^c, C^c)$, yet $P(A | B) > P(A | B^c)$.
>
> (a) Can Simpson’s paradox occur if $A$ and $B$ are independent? If so, give a concrete example (with both numbers and an interpretation); if not, prove that it is impossible.
>
> (b) Can Simpson’s paradox occur if $A$ and $C$ are independent? If so, give a concrete example (with both numbers and an interpretation); if not, prove that it is impossible.
>
> (c) Can Simpson’s paradox occur if $B$ and $C$ are independent? If so, give a concrete example (with both numbers and an interpretation); if not, prove that it is impossible.

**Answers:**

(a)
$P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$

By this equation, $P(A|B,C) = P(A|C)$ and $P(A|B^c,C) = P(A|C)$. Hence, these two expressions are equal. So Simpson's Paradox does not apply here.

(b)
$P(A \cap C) = P(A) P(C)$

By the above equation,  $P(A|B,C) = P(A|B)$ and $P(A|B^c,C) = P(A|B^c)$. By the inequality $P(A|B,C^c) < P(A|B^c, C^c)$, $P(A|B)$ should be less than $P(A|B^c)$. This then contradicts the final result that $P(A|B) > P(A|B^c)$.

(c)
Here I am not sure how to proceed. I am not sure how $B$ and $C$ being independent would affect the occurrence of $A$.

Comment: Dumb question: what does `P(A,B)` mean in your notation?

Comment: $P(A | B,C)$ means Probability of A given B given C.

Comment: So `P(A|(B|C))`? Or `P((A|B)|C)`. Or is 'given' associative (my math is a little rusty)

Comment: I think they are both equal. The results would be the same no matter the order.

Comment: just because A is independent of C, this does not guarantee conditional independence correct?  P(A | B,C ) = P(A|B) requires conditional independence.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. So, in that case, the occurrence of Simpson's Paradox would be inapplicable in the first and second cases correct?

Answer (score 1):

It cannot occur.
If B, C are independent, then $B, B^C, C, C^C$ are pairwise independent. Then, $P(C|B)=P(C|B^C)=P(C), P(C^C|B)P(C^C|B^C)=P(C^C)$, by the law of total probability, $P(A|B) - P(A|B^C) = (P(A|C,B)P(C|B)+P(A|C^C,B)P(C^C|B)) - (P(A|C,B^C)P(C|B^C)+P(A|C^C,B^C)P(C^C|B^C) )= (P(A|C,B)- P(A|C,B^C))P(C) + P(A|C^C,B)P(C^C)<0$